# sql group query with order by and limit

Tags: sql, mysql

My table strucutre is as follows

```
| id   | cmp      | empid | empname | ttm  
+------+----------+-------+---------+------
|    2 | xyz      | 12    | swap    |    2 
|    2 | xyz      | 12    | sag     |    3
|    2 | xyz      | 14    | azr     |    1 
|    3 | pqr      | 2     | ron     |    2 
|    3 | pqr      | 22    | rah     |    1 
|    3 | pqr      | 32    | pra     |    5
```

I have done query on that like as follows

```
(select * from test.companies where id = '2' order by ttm desc limit 2)
union
(select * from test.companies where id = '3' order by ttm desc limit 2);
```

it will give output as follows

```
| id   | cmp      | empid | empname | ttm  
+------+----------+-------+---------+------
|    2 | wissen   | 12    | sag     |    3
|    2 | wissen   | 12    | swap    |    2 
|    3 | prolinkd | 32    | pra     |    5
|    3 | prolinkd | 2     | ron     |    2
```

but i want output as follows

```
| id   | cmp      | empid | empname | ttm  
+------+----------+-------+---------+------
|    3 | prolinkd | 32    | pra     |    5
|    3 | prolinkd | 2     | ron     |    2
|    2 | wissen   | 12    | sag     |    3 
|    2 | wissen   | 12    | swap    |    2
```

means which company has maximum ttm it will be shown first

If some one knows plz reply

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather ugly looking, and ugly sounding, but it should do what you want.  It retrieves the "maxttm" for each company with each record, then uses that in sorting to allow you to assign priority to companies based on their highest ttm.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT *,
        (SELECT ttm FROM test.companies ic WHERE ic.id = oc.id ORDER BY ttm DESC LIMIT 1) AS maxttm
        FROM test.companies oc WHERE id = '2' ORDER BY ttm DESC LIMIT 2)
    UNION
    (SELECT *,
        (SELECT ttm FROM test.companies ic WHERE ic.id = oc.id ORDER BY ttm DESC LIMIT 1) AS maxttm
        FROM test.companies oc WHERE id = '3' ORDER BY ttm DESC LIMIT 2)
) AS myunion ORDER BY maxttm, id;
```

PS. thanks to inti whose query I shamelessly based this on.

Comment: thanks above query really help full for me once again thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM (

    (select * from test.companies where id = '2' order by ttm desc limit 2)
    union
    (select * from test.companies where id = '3' order by ttm desc limit 2)

) as myunion ORDER BY ttm;
```

gets what you need, and orders it by ttm.

Comment: @Swapnil Sonawane so you wanted the companies grouped, but ordered by their biggest ttm value, well thankfully @Jeff Parker understood it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from test.companies 
where id in ('2','3') 
and ttm > 1
order by ttm desc, id
```

Comment: Based on the example data, I don't think this'll match.  It seems he wants all records for the company with the higher TTM value to come first (eg. Company #3 has the highest TTM, so all records for company #3 come first). Also if you do it this way, I don't see how you can limit each ID to only the top 2 records.